# Looking for a commutative ring satisfying certain conditions

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, inverse, positive-characteristic

I'm looking for a commutative ring $R$ (with unit) which is of characteristic 2 and which possesses elements $x$ and $y$ such that the following holds

$x^2$ and $y^2$ are inverses of one another but $x$ and $y$ are not; $x, y, 1+x, 1+y$ are all units.

An example of such a ring or reasoning as to why one cannot exist would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @user26857 I was going to add some motivation but as I wrote some it felt a little tedious and unenlightening, it arose as a subproblem of a subproblem of a subproblem of a problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have 
$ (x^{-1})^2=(x^2)^{-1}=y^2$ and hence
$$ (y-x^{-1})^2=0,$$
so $R$ has zero divisors.
This motivates the following example:

Let $R=\mathbb F_4[\epsilon] =\mathbb F_4[X]/(X^2)$ and $x$ a generator of the cyclic group $F_4^\times$. Then $x^3=1$ and $x\ne 1$, so $x^2+x+1=0$. Let $y=x^2+\epsilon$. Then $y^2=x$.
We verify

- $x\in R^\times$ because $x^3=1$
- $y\in R^\times$ because $y^2=x\in R^\times$
- $1+x\in R^\times$ because $1+x\in\mathbb F_4$ and $x\ne1$; or explicitly: $(1+x)^3=x+x^2=1$
- $1+y\in R^\times$ because $(1+y)^2=1+x\in R^\times$
- $xy=1+x\epsilon\ne1$
- $x^2y^2=x^2x=1$

It was not required, but in this example, $x, y, 1+x,1+y$ are even four *distinct* units.

Comment: Hah, I was a little puzzled about the first equation but then I reread and noticed the characteristic 2 part. My bad :)